# How to install X-Apps in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

Mint is creating some universal X-Apps. I find Pix to be quite interesting, very advanced interface concept, something like MS Ribbon interface, but better. Does anyone knows how to install this X-Apps in Ubuntu?

Comment: http://kylenubuntu.blogspot.nl/2016/07/running-x-apps-on-ubuntu-devices.html

Comment: Thanks. It is very useful. It's easier for me in Xubuntu.